# Segmentation fault when running hs_init(0, 0) for ffi

Tags: haskell, ffi

I am trying to call Haskell functions from python.
I have the following make file:

```
GHC=ghc
GHC_RUNTIME_LINKER_FLAG=-lHSrts-ghc7.4.1

libffi-example.so: Example.o wrapper.o
    $(GHC) -o $@ -shared -dynamic -fPIC $^ $(GHC_RUNTIME_LINKER_FLAG)

Example_stub.h Example.o: Example.hs
    $(GHC) -c -dynamic -fPIC Example.hs

wrapper.o: wrapper.c Example_stub.h
    $(GHC) -c -dynamic -fPIC wrapper.c

clean:
    rm -f *.hi *.o *_stub.[ch]

clean-all:
    rm -f *.hi *.o *_stub.[ch] *.so


# Runs the example Python program
example: libffi-example.so
    python program.py
```

The only thing wrapper.c does it creating wrappers for `hs_init` by calling `hs_init(0,0);`. The wrapper is called `example_init`

I get a segmentation fault when running `make example`, in `example_init` (ie when calling `hs_init(0,0)`).

Can someone tell me why this is and/or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: `hs_init` takes pointers to argv and argc. Try passing proper pointers, e.g.  `hs_init(&argc, &argv);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ought to work:

> "Moreover, `hs_init()` may be called with NULL for both argc and argv, signalling the absence of command line arguments."

It seems to be a bug in ghc-7.2.1 to ghc-7.4.1:

**RFib.hs:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module RFib where

fib :: Int -> Int
fib n
    | n >= 0    = go 0 1 n
    | even n    = -go 0 1 (-n)
    | otherwise = go 0 1 (-n)
      where
        go a _ 0 = a
        go a b k = go b (a+b) (k-1)

foreign export ccall "rfib" fib :: Int -> Int
```

**rfib.c:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <HsFFI.h>

int rfib(int);

int main(void) {
    hs_init(0,0);
    printf("%d\n", rfib(35));
    hs_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ rm rfib.o RFib.hi RFib.o a.out
$ ghc-7.0.2 -O2 -Wall -no-hs-main RFib.hs rfib.c && ./a.out
[1 of 1] Compiling RFib             ( RFib.hs, RFib.o )
Linking a.out ...
9227465
$ rm rfib.o RFib.hi RFib.o a.out
$ ghc-7.0.4 -O2 -Wall -no-hs-main RFib.hs rfib.c && ./a.out
[1 of 1] Compiling RFib             ( RFib.hs, RFib.o )
Linking a.out ...
9227465
$ rm rfib.o RFib.hi RFib.o a.out
$ ghc-7.2.1 -O2 -Wall -no-hs-main RFib.hs rfib.c && ./a.out
[1 of 1] Compiling RFib             ( RFib.hs, RFib.o )
Linking a.out ...
Speicherzugriffsfehler
$ rm rfib.o RFib.hi RFib.o a.out
$ ghc-7.2.2 -O2 -Wall -no-hs-main RFib.hs rfib.c && ./a.out
[1 of 1] Compiling RFib             ( RFib.hs, RFib.o )
Linking a.out ...
Speicherzugriffsfehler
$ rm rfib.o RFib.hi RFib.o a.out
$ ghc-7.4.1 -O2 -Wall -no-hs-main RFib.hs rfib.c && ./a.out
[1 of 1] Compiling RFib             ( RFib.hs, RFib.o )
Linking a.out ...
Speicherzugriffsfehler
$ rm rfib.o RFib.hi RFib.o a.out
$ ghc-7.4.2 -O2 -Wall -no-hs-main RFib.hs rfib.c && ./a.out
[1 of 1] Compiling RFib             ( RFib.hs, RFib.o )
Linking a.out ...
9227465
$ rm rfib.o RFib.hi RFib.o a.out
$ ghc -O2 -Wall -no-hs-main RFib.hs rfib.c && ./a.out
[1 of 1] Compiling RFib             ( RFib.hs, RFib.o )
Linking a.out ...
9227465
```

Changing two lines in `rfib.c`:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    hs_init(&argc,&argv);
```

it works with all versions (>= 7.0 that I have installed).

So to fix it

- pass `&argc` and `&argv`
- upgrade GHC

are the two most obvious ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upgrading ghc to 7.4.2 worked with hs_init(NULL, NULL). Awesome :)